# R memory management with mclapply and data.table

Tags: r, memory, data.table, mclapply

I have a really big data object X (10+ GB say).  I want to do some operations in categories inside the object, in parallel to make them fast (e.g. many fits of a prediction model).  In terms of RAM usage, is it more efficient to either:

1) pass in the whole data.table object to the children processes, then do operations on the whole object (such as subsetting, but could be other things), then do intensive operations on the smaller set of data.  Because we are forking, does this mean the children won't make a copy of X if we do not modify it?  e.g. if we subset X and assign it to say v (as in the example below), does the child process use only extra RAM for v, or does it make a copy of X inside the child, so effectively all the spawned children processes consume RAM the size of X in addition to the parent.

2) split the data in the parent into a list, where each element contains the necessary data to do the intensive operations on, then pass into the children forked processes only what is required?  This approach means we effectively double the amount of memory used in the parent before running mclapply, because the list effectively contains all the same data in the original big data table, but split up correctly.

Here is a toy example doing what would normally be trivial in data.table anyway without mclapply, but gets the point across:

```
X <- data.table(x1 = rnorm(1:1000), category = rep(c("a", "b", "c", "d"), 250))

# 1 Pass in the big object:
doIntensiveStuff <- function(y, cat) {
    # y is big, all categories
    # now going to operate on all of y, to subset the rows we need, then do calculations we need
    v <- y[category == cat,]
    mean(v[, x1])
}

z <- lapply(X = X[, unique(category)], FUN = doIntensiveStuff, y = X)#, mc.cores = length(X[, unique(category)]))




 # First approach, pass in the X <- data.table(x1 = rnorm(1:1000), category = rep(c("a", "b", "c", "d"), 250))


doIntensiveStuff <- function(y, cat) {
    # y is big, all categories
    # now going to operate on all of y, to subset the rows we need, then do calculations we need
    v <- y[category == cat,]
    mean(v[, x1])
}

z <- lapply(X = X[, unique(category)], FUN = doIntensiveStuff, y = X)#, mc.cores = length(X[, unique(category)]))


# Second approach. Double the data in the parent, but the forked children get only what they need:

doIntensiveStuff2 <- function(yJustOneCategory, cat) {
    # yJustOneCategory is a smaller object inside the child forked process, while the large X object remains in the parent.
    yJustOneCategory[, mean(x1)]
}

z2 <- mclapply(X = split(X, by = "category"), FUN = doIntensiveStuff2, mc.cores = length(X[, unique(category)]))

all.equal(as.numeric(unlist(z)), as.numeric(unlist(z2)))
# TRUE

    doIntensiveStuff2 <- function(yJustOneCategory, cat) {
        # yJustOneCategory is a smaller object inside the child forked process, while the large X object remains in the parent.
        yJustOneCategory[, mean(x1)]
    }

    z2 <- mclapply(X = split(X, by = "category"), FUN = doIntensiveStuff2, mc.cores = length(X[, unique(category)]))

    all.equal(as.numeric(unlist(z)), as.numeric(unlist(z2)))
    # TRUE
```

Help in clarifying my understanding of how memory is used in R for forked processes with big data would be appreciated.

Comment: Do you know that some data.table operations are already parallelized?

Comment: Of course.  I have some big data I keep in data.tables, for which I might combine with other data in the children processes and do stuff etc. Was just trying to make a minimal example